# where is the codes in Global.asax in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i create a default project in mvc3 and published it on my host ,what about codes in file:
Global.asax after publishing there is a one line code in it:
where is the codes?

```
ï»¿<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MvcApplication1.MvcApplication"  Language="C#" %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is in `Global.asax.cs`.  In Visual Studio if you you look next to the `Global.asax` file in your object explorer, there will be a down arrow.  If you click that you should see the `Global.asax.cs` file.  And just like any other file in VS, you can double-click that and it should open up that file containing your code.

Comment: after publishing there is not available Global.asax.cs.

Comment: That's because it's a compiled web application.  You'll have to view it in Visual Studio as a project.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC uses web application mode as default vs web site. A web application is a compiled mode. This means that when you ship all source code is stripped away and compiled into assemblies. So you deploy only assemblies (int the `bin` folder) and views. So the `Global.asax.cs` file that you have in design time is simply compiled into the `bin/YouAppName.dll` assembly and it is referenced from the Global.asax markup file.